# Passing headers and query params in HTTparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-headers, httparty

How to pass query params and headers in post method using HTTparty. I am doing as follows
But it throws

```
query = {:method => "neworder", :nonce => 1404996028, :order_type => "buy", :quantity=>1,:rate=>1}
headers = {:key=> "87819747209090199871234", :sign=> "0a3888ac7f8e411ad73a0a503c55db70a291rsf34bfb9f9a47147d5200882674f717f6ede475669f3453"}

HTTParty.post("https://www.acb.com/api/v2/market/LTC_BTC/", :query => query, :headers => headers )
```

But it throws the following error. How to handle query string params and headers with HTTparty.

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:172:in `capitalize': undefined method `split' for :key:Symbol (NoMethodError)
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:165:in `block in each_capitalized'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:164:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:164:in `each_capitalized'
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use [Strings](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html) for your hash keys instead of [Symbols](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html).

```
query = { 
  "method"     => "neworder",
  "nonce"      => 1404996028,
  "order_type" => "buy",
  "quantity"   => 1,
  "rate"       => 1
}
headers = { 
  "key"  => "8781974720909019987",
  "sign" => "0a3888ac7f8e411ad73a0a503c55db70a291bfb9f9a47147d5200882674f717f6ede475669f3453" 
}

HTTParty.post(
  "https://www.acb.com/api/v2/market/LTC_BTC/", 
  :query => query,
  :headers => headers
)
```

It was probably only the `headers` that were causing a problem due to the error occurring in [`net/http/header.rb:172`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http/header.rb#L172). The important info being `undefined method 'split' for :key:Symbol (NoMethodError)`

Symbol error in [`irb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell):

```
irb(main):002:0> "Something".split
=> ["Something"]

irb(main):003:0> :Something.split
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for :Something:Symbol
        from (irb):3
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I find that with some API calls using `:body` instead of `:query` will work. In general be mindful of how you name the request parameters

Answer (score 10):

It's been a bit old question, but we had the same issue recently, so I try to attach my solutions:

1) The answer above is working:

```
  "headers": {
      "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"
    }
```

2) Alternatively, the other solution is:

```
  headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer #{token}"
    }
```