# Fixing 416 error: HTTParty

Tags: ruby, http, get, http-headers, httparty

Getting a 416 error when trying to GET a website with HTTParty. Works just fine in the browser.

I have never gotten this error before, so I went online and found this:

> It occurs when the server is unable to fulfill the request. This may
> be, for example, because the client asked for the 800th-900th bytes of
> a document, but the document is only 200 bytes long.
>
> The request includes a Range request-header field, and not any of the
> range-specifier values in this field overlaps the current extent of
> the selected resource, and also the request does not include an
> If-Range request-header field.

Wondering if anyone has gotten 416 with HTTParty before and if there is a way to prevent this form happening. Thanks

Example website where error occurs:
http://www.bizjournals.com/jacksonville/blog/morning-edition/2014/07/teens-make-up-less-of-summer-workforce-than-ever.html

Answer (score 1):

It appears that bizjournals is able to detect you are a bot (not accessing in the browser) and therefore returns a 416.

```
irb(main):005:0> HTTParty.get('http://www.bizjournals.com/jacksonville/blog/morning-edition/2014/07/teens-make-up-less-of-summer-workforce-than-ever.html').body
=> "........As you were browsing <strong>http://www.bizjournals.com</strong> something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen........"
```

You could either ask bizjournals to allow you to make requests or try to change the headers to make bizjournals think you are not a bot.

Comment: Any insight on how I can change headers with httparty?

Comment: This post shows how to pass headers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691483/passing-headers-and-query-params-in-httparty