# RestClient/HTTParty authentication parameters not being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client, httparty

For API call I've tried..

In RestClient

**Works but is wrong:**

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(
method: :get,
url: 'https://api.data.charitynavigator.org/v2/Organizations?app_id=2b1ffdad&app_key=XXXX',
)
```

**Doesn't Work (403: Forbidden):**

```
response = ::RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: 'https://api.data.charitynavigator.org/v2/Organizations?app_id=2b1ffdad', 
headers: {app_key: 'XXXX'})
```

In HTTParty

**Also doesn't work (Authentication parameters missing):**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'


class Charity
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'https://api.data.charitynavigator.org/v2/'

  def posts

    headers = {
      "app_id"  => "2b1ffdad",
      "app_key"  => "XXXX"
    }

    self.class.get("/Organizations/",
    :headers => headers
    )
  end
end


charity = Charity.new
puts charity.posts
```

For reference: https://charity.3scale.net/docs/data-api/reference

Is it syntax? I've also looked into Faraday but ran into similar issues there. Many 3rd party API examples with rails seem to be using long outdated APIs so it's been hard piecing everything together.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Really want to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand your saying **Works but is wrong** but Charity Navigator Data API request the sending **`app_id` and `app_key` keys through the parameters, not header**.

Your first code looks correct.

Second code, `app_key` key was sent by header, not params. So API response 403.

Third code, coded with httpart gem, dose not use parameters but headers. So Charity Navigator Data API response `Authentication parameters missing` error. It's normal.

```
require 'httparty'

class StackExchange
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://api.data.charitynavigator.org/v2/'

  def posts
    options = { 
      query: {
        app_id: '2b1ffdad',
        app_key: 'XXXX'
      }
    }

    self.class.get("/Organizations/", options)
  end
end

charity = Charity.new
puts charity.posts
```

But you can use parameters by `query option` in httparty. Read the [httparty docs](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty#examples) and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24691914/3910390). And you can [use parameters options](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#usage-raw-url) in rest-client gem, too. And I recommend use it strongly.